# Troubleshooting AOP in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

Are there any AOP diagnostics that can be enabled on Spring Boot?  I'm having trouble trying to figuring out which of my Pointcuts are evaluating correctly.  For example, I have something like this

```
@Pointcut("... ")
    public void foo() {
    }

@Pointcut("... ")
    public void bar() {
    }

@Around("foo() && bar()")
    public Object doSomething(final ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("*** do something");
        
    }
```

My `doSomething()` method is not getting executed, and I can't figure out why.  Obviously, the logic is a bit more complicateds than shown here with just 2 pointcuts.  Is there some sort of diagnostic logging I ca enable that would show me that value of each of the pointcuts? Or something which tells me why `doSomethig()` is or is not executed?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to log something that is **not** called. Do you mean something like logging pointcut matching, i.e. "pointcut A matches method B"? But actually, you already know that your pointcut does not match, so you would not learn anything new. Have you tried to check step by step which of your multiple AND/OR-connected pointcuts match separately in order to find out which part(s) is/are the non-matching ones? You could simply add several temporary advice methods matching a sub-expression and logging something when triggered.

Comment: AOP obviously has to make a decision as to whether or not to call something, so I'm looking for that information to be logged.  I know my pointcut doesn't match, but I don't know *why* it doesn't match.  There are many conditions, so I'm trying to evaluate the individual pieces.  So I'm looking for an evaluation of the pointcut condition.  I was hoping there was already something built-in

Comment: Yes, but when that decision is made depends both on the pointcut types involved and on the AOP framework used. Are you using Spring AOP or AspectJ? You did not really make that clear. Not knowing your pointcuts also does not make it easier to reply.